List view being pushed down as I push to another view
I'm working in this search view using SwiftUI. There's a List in my view being populated by a ForEach, each row takes the user to another view. But when I push another view, the back button from the navigation bar of the new view pushes the whole List view down.
Here is the code:
struct SearchView: View {
    @Binding var isSearching : Bool
    @FocusState var isFocused : Bool
    @StateObject var viewModel = SearchVM()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.secondaryColor)
                        TextField("Pesquisar...", text: $viewModel.searchText )
                            .focused($isFocused)
                    }.modifier(OutlinedCardStyle(padding: 12))
                    
                }
                .textFont(style: .montserrat14)
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                        isSearching.toggle()
                        isFocused = isSearching
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Cancelar")
                        .bold()
                }).padding(.leading,5)
            }.padding([.horizontal,.top])
            List {
                ForEach($viewModel.matchedSections, id: \.id) { $section in
                    Section($section.sectionName.wrappedValue){
                        ForEach($section.subSections, id: \.id){ subsection in
                            NavigationLink{
                                AppointmentView()
                            }label:{
                                Text(subsection.sectionName.wrappedValue)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
               
            } .listStyle(.plain)
                .animation(.smooth, value: viewModel.matchedSections)
                
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear{
            isFocused = isSearching
        }
    }
}

I tried to embend the view in a scroll view to see if there's was something related, since something similar already had happened to me and doing this fixed the problem. However this made the list simply disappear. Doing some searching I found that this is the normal behavior when trying to put a list inside a scroll view.
I removed the list and left only the ForEach, and the navigation worked fine. So the problem is really in the list. Is there a way to work around this? I'd really like to still use the native list since creating the sections its easier.
I found this question that shows the effect of what's happening in my code but still have no exact answer.

It might be worth trying the workaround from this answer: How to show large navigation title when using NavigationStack and .searchable?

Yeah I gave this a shot, but the problems persists. the OnDisappear function only runs after the the new view is already pushed.

Yeah, since swiftUI does not have a viewWillDisappear function, my solution was to to change the isShowing variable to false in the .onAppear of the view being pushed. It works now
